# List of available services

Tags: debian, services

Is there any command that would show all the **available services** in my wheezy Debian based OS?

I know that in order to see all the **running services** you can use `service --status-all`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721149/check-if-a-particular-service-is-running-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Wheezy uses SysV init, and all the services are controlled with special shell scripts in `/etc/init.d`, so `ls /etc/init.d` will list them.  These files also contain a description of the service at the top, and the directory contains a `README`.

Some but not all of them have a `.sh` suffix, you should leave that off when using, eg., `update-rc.d`.

Answer (score 85):

On Debian jessie try: `service --status-all`.

It is in the `sysvinit-utils` package.

Answer (score 22):

```
service --status-all
```

Will list all services with a status code, being stopped or off (-), started or on (+), or unknown (?), which means no status code section in their init.d script. **Not just running services.**

Answer (score 21):

[As said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220927/209677), with systemd would be

```
systemctl --full --type service --all
```

From [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html):

> `-l`, `--full` Do not ellipsize unit names, process tree entries, journal output, or truncate unit descriptions in the output of status, list-units, list-jobs, and list-timers.
>
> `-a`, `--all` When listing units with `list-units`, also show inactive units and units which are following other units. When showing unit/job/manager properties, show all properties regardless whether they are set or not.

Also useful, [from ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Analyzing_the_system_state):

```bsh
systemctl             # List running units
systemctl list-units  # Idem
systemctl --failed    # List failed units
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Or

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep yourservicenameorpartofit
```

Answer (score 0):

**/etc/init.d** contains scripts used by the System V init tools (SysVinit).

List executable:

```
ls -F /etc/init.d/ | grep '*$'
```