# Ubuntu full list of available services

Tags: ubuntu, services

This question is very similar to this one: [List of available services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108591/list-of-available-services)

For my specific case, I'm wondering if there is a specific command to show the full list of services under Ubuntu.

I did run a `ls /etc/init.d` and it does show a pretty comprehensive list, but some entries are missing. I did see `apache2`, `myslq`, `gdm`, and a whole lot of others.

But some of them are missing. One example is `plexmediaserver` (I've installed plex server recently and had some difficulties in finding the name of it's service)

So to rephrase this question in as few words as possible:
Is there a way to get the full list of possibilities of `{x}`  for

```
service {x} status
```

Note: using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Does `service --status-all` do what you want?

Comment: Check in `/etc/init/` too if you are using upstart..

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, no `plexmediaserver` is still skipped

Comment: @heemayl, doing a `ls /etc/init/` shows a `plexmediaserver.conf` (and many more). This is pretty close to what i want. Thanks!

Comment: which Ubuntu release are you on?

Comment: I'm on 15.04. Your first comment lead me to my answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system` too as the init is systemd in 15.04 ..

Comment: That just shows a `cryptmount.service` file

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Since Ubuntu has recently switched over to systemd, some services will be listed by upstart.

```
service --status-all
```

and others, by systemd

```
systemctl -l --type service --all
```

or as root

```
systemctl -r --type service --all
```

However software still using the init system will likely be listed in

```
/etc/init.d
```

Looking through all of those will yield most services registered on the system.

There is a good summary on systemd over on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd)

Answer (score 7):

You'll need a combination of commands, depending on your Ubuntu version. Before systemd became the init system (pre-15.04), the following would suffice:

```
service --status-all # for sysv init scripts
initctl list         # for Upstart jobs
```

Some services might be listed by both `service` and `initctl`, in which case the Upstart job would usually be the right one.

For the case of `systemd`, [John Petit's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220927/70524) provides the necessary commands.